# Algorithm to find a number pair's closest match in a list of numbers

Tags: algorithm, search

I have a program with a very specific algorithmic need.  I need to search a list of numbers to find the position in the list that best aligns with a pair of search numbers.  I'm defining 'best aligns' as the sum of the differences at that alignment.

For example, if I have the following list of numbers:

```
12  18 -20  45  11  34   6  -8
```

...and I'm searching for the pair **44 13**, then the algorithm should return 3, because this alignment is best (has a total difference of only 5), and 3 is the index of where the alignment begins

```
index:             0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
list:             12  18 -20  45  11  34   6  -8
search alignment: --  --  --  43  14  --  --  -- 
difference:       --  --  --   2   3  --  --  --
```

I'm currently using an obvious brute-force approach - simply finding the difference for each alignment and remembering the best.  However, this is something of a bottleneck for my program, so any improvements would be helpful.

The only optimisation I have come up with is somewhat trivial: if for an alignment the difference for the first number in the pair exceeds the current best total difference, skip to the next alignment without bothering to check the second number in the pair.  It helps, but not much.

If it's relevant, the lists are searched multiple times, so if there's some kind of initial sorting that would speed up future searches, I'd be interested.

I'd appreciate any ideas anyone has, even if it's just a link to a Wikipedia page for a relevant algorithm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recast this problem as a nearest neighbor search in 2D. Take all pairs of numbers and see them as points of the 2D plane. Your distance function is called the 1-norm (sum of absolute differences). With your query pair, you are looking for the closest point.

So what you are looking for is a fast solution to the nearest-neighbor search in 2D with the 1-norm distance. It is known that after O(N.Log(N)) preprocessing requiring O(N) storage (construction of the Voronoi diagram), all queries can be answered in time O(Log(N)).

Alternatively (for much simpler implementation), you could use a 2D-tree (kD-tree in 2D dimensions). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree

If you can afford the storage, a gridding solution is also possible: draw a square grid over your points and group them per tile. For a query pair, locate it in the grid and explore from this tile in concentric "circles" of neighboring tiles and make an exhaustive comparison with the points they contain.

Comment: Concentric "circles" are dangerous. Point (6, 6) is closer to (0, 0) than point (10, 1). But latter is better then former in terms of our task.

Comment: For the 1-norm distance, circles are diamonds.

Answer (score 1):

As @Yves_Daoust said, you can represent pairs in list as 2D-points.
Then, you can place them in quadtree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree. Searching the nearest to arbitrary point executes in O(lg(n)) time in this structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an auxiliary array, where you describe your pairs `(l, u)` in terms of midpoint `m` and width `w` plus the original index in the list. Sort that array and use binary search to find the closest match of the centre point. Your best alignment should then be in the vicinity of that match.

Your criterion

```
d = abs(l1 - l2) + abs(u1 - u2)
```

would then become

```
d = abs(dm - dw/2) + abs(dm + dw/2), dm = m1 - m2, dw = w1 - w2
```

That leaves the question of how close to the match found by binary search you should look. You could start from there and work your way both forwardand backwards in the list until the difference between the midpoins is greater than your optimum distance.